# maclaurin series $\ln \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I know that the Maclaurin seriess is: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n(x)^n$ and $c_n = \frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}$

$\ln \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)$

$f^0 = \ln (1+0) - \ln (1-0) = 0$

$f^{(1)} = \frac{4x}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2)} = 0$

$f^{(2)} = \frac{12x^4 + 4}{(1+x^2)^2(1-x^2)^2} = 4$

$\frac{0x^1}{1} + \frac{0x^2}{2!} + \frac{4x^2}{3!} ...$

I must have done a mistake, because I can't find the answer with that and $f^{(3)}$ seems insane.

Comment: Do you know the maclaurin series of $\ln(1+t)$? Then by expanding with log rules and substituting $t = \pm x^2$ you can derive the series of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function is defined for $|x|<1$, you can write it as
$$
f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)-\ln(1-x^2)
$$
You surely know the Maclaurin series
$$
\ln(1+t)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^n}{n}
\qquad
\ln(1-t)=-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{t^n}{n}
$$
and so
$$
\ln(1+x^2)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{n}
$$
and
$$
\ln(1-x^2)=-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}
$$
Hence
$$
f(x)=
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{n}+
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}
$$
What are the terms that “survive”?

> Only those with odd $n$, so you get $$\sum_{\substack{n\ge1\\n\text{ odd}}}\frac{2x^{2n}}{n}=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{2x^{4n-2}}{2n-1}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{2x^{4n+2}}{2n+1}$$

Comment: How
$\ln(1-t)=-\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{t^n}{n}$

If

 $\ln(1+t)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^n}{n}
\qquad$

And


$f(x)=
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{n}+
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}
$

I'm not sure about $\sum + \sum$ I guess $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}*2x^{4n}}{2n}$
But this is not the answer.

Comment: The answer should be $\frac{2x^{4n-2}}{2n-1}$

Comment: This is certainly the way to do it. Just make sure there are no algebra errors, and you should be there.

Comment: Thanks for your help.